# Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[NSLayoutConstraint]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am creating NSLayoutConstraint programatically, but ending up with following error :

> Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type
>   '[NSLayoutConstraint]'

Here is my code :

```
let notificationHorizontalConstraints: [AnyObject] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|",
                options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                metrics: metricsDict,
                views: viewsDict)
```

As per my knowledge `AnyObject` is the protocol to which all classes implicitly conform. Then why it is not working `'[AnyObject]'`?

Comment: I don't think this line is the problem. The error sounds like it's occuring when you're later trying to use this array (tying to implicitly downcast an `[AnyObject]` to `[NSLayoutConstraint]`, you should be explicitly downcasting with `as`). I just copy and pasted this line into a Swift project and it works fine without error. However, I don't know why you wouldn't want to be explicit about the array's type here. I would never recommend using `[AnyObject]` here.

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace `[AnyObject]` and `[NSLayoutConstraint]` might solve your warning.in Swift don't use AnyObject just tell the compiler explicitly that its an `NSLayoutConstraint`.

```
let notificationHorizontalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]
```

Comment: Yes, this will work but I want to know why [AnyObject] is not working in Swift2.0 ?